# using system date command for data conversion using awk variables

Tags: shell, awk

Log file is looking like:

```
28 Feb 2014,12:43:10,SAST,1821996800,10.144.22.91,494225040,"CONNECT",STARTED,0,0,0,10.144.22.91:59172,->,1.1.1.6:80
28 Feb 2014,12:43:10,SAST,1821996800,10.144.22.91,494225040,"CONNECT",TERMINATED,0,0,0,10.144.22.91:59172,->,1.1.1.6:80
```

Desired output:

```
2014/02/28,12:43:10,SAST,1821996800,10.144.22.91,494225040,"CONNECT",STARTED,0,0,0,10.144.22.91:59172,->,1.1.1.6:80
2014/02/28,12:43:10,SAST,1821996800,10.144.22.91,494225040,"CONNECT",TERMINATED,0,0,0,10.144.22.91:59172,->,1.1.1.6:80
```

Shell Command that is doing the conversion:

```
date -d "28 Feb 2014" +%Y/%m/%d
```

Question:
How I can do this conversion using awk (later on I need to do conversions between different time zones that's why date command is the one to be used and no sed or other methods to manipulate the chars)
For now tried several options but none are working properly:

Version 1 (for some reason, date command is not run using the full awk variable and give me error so no result):

```
 awk '
    BEGIN { FS = "," }
    {   
    while ("date -d $1 +%Y/%m/%d" | getline ddd) print ddd;
    }
  ' _SOURCE_FILE
```

Version 2 (this is not working as desired but give me an extra line and add a "0" in it that is the system execution code):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = "," }
    {   
    $1 = system("date -d \"$1\" +%Y/%m/%d")
    print $0
    }
  ' _SOURCE_FILE
```

Help is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` doesn't expand variables inside strings, use concatenation. There's also no need to use `while` when the command only produces one line of output.

```
"date -d " $1 "+%Y/%m/%d" | getline ddd;
$1 = ddd;
print $0;
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar for your quick reply.
I had some troubles to understand how to use your example as I'm getting errors.
date: extra operand `2014+%Y/%m/%d'
Try `date --help' for more information.